# MySQLパスワードをmysql_config_editorで設定している場合、crontab経由で、shファイルを実行したときだけ、mysqldump結果のファイルサイズが0になるのですが

Tags: mysql, linux, shellscript, sh

**環境**
・CentOS
・MySQL 5.6 … パスワードはmysql_config_editorで設定
・Linuxユーザ名 … test

---

**下記コマンドを実行したら、期待した通りファイルが作成されるのですが、**

```
sh hoge.sh
```

▼hoge.sh

> mysqldump --single-transaction -u データベースユーザ名 データベース名 >
>   /home/test/バックアップディレクトリ名/ファイル名

---

**crontab経由で、shファイルを実行したら、サイズが0のファイルが作成され、dumpデータが取得できません**
・cronのエラーメールも送られてきません(cronエラーではないから？)

> ```
> 1 15 * * * root /bin/bash /home/test/hoge.sh
> ```

---

**権限関連が原因のような気もするのですが、rootで実行したら何でもいけるわけではないのでしょうか？**

```
ls -la
```

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 test test  270  1月 19 14:52 2017 hoge.sh

---

**追記**
・その後、色々試した結果、shファイルに記述しているコマンド内のmysqldumpにpオプションを付与すれば、crontab経由からも正常にファイル取得できることがわかりました
・しかし、mysql_config_editorを使用することで、コマンドからパスワード指定しなくてもログインできるよう設定しているのですが、この方式ではcrontab経由から、データ取得できないのでしょうか？
・mysqldumpエラーをファイル出力しようと思い、「-r ファイル名」としたのですが、取得できませんでした

---

**再追記**

・現状をようやく確認できました(cron以前の問題？)
・hoge.shをtestユーザとして直接実行すると、正常動作します
・hoge.shをrootユーザとして直接実行すると、下記エラー発生

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) when trying to connect

・hoge.shのdumpコマンドにパスワードを付与してcron経由で(rootユーザとして)実行すると、正常動作します

・mysqlテーブルを「select * from  user;」すると、rootユーザもtestユーザもいます。パスワードは同じです

```
$ mysql_config_editor print --all
```

[test]
user = test
password = *****
host = localhost
[mysqldump]
user = root
password = *****
[root]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost

そもそも根本的なことが分かっていないのですが、shの実行権限が何であれ、MySQLにはsh内のmysqldumpコマンドで記述したデータベースユーザ名でアクセスするわけではないのでしょうか？「mysqldump -u データベースユーザ名」

Comment: 出力で` > output`してますが` > output 2> error`でエラーの内容はどうでしょうか？また、crontabを実行しているユーザはrootでしょうか？(上手いことコードブロックがコメントで出来ないorz)

Comment: 「/home/test/バックアップディレクトリ名/ファイル名 2> error」へ変更してみましたが、何も出力されませんでした。crontabを実行しているユーザ？　どうやって調べるのでしょうか？　crontabファイル自体のls -laは「-rw-r--r--   1 root root    15410  1月 19 17:53 2017 crontab」と表示されます

Comment: そもそもcronを使わずにrootユーザでhoge.shを実行して正しく動作することは確認されていますか？

Comment: はい。「sudo sh hoge.sh」をコマンド実行すると、正常動作します

Comment: 「コマンド実行したら正常動作している」ことを確かめたはずでしたが、私の勘違いだったようです(何度やっても再現できないので)。「mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'データベースユーザ名'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect」。そうなると、sh以前の問題だと思われるので、質問を「MySQLパスワードをmysql_config_editorで設定している場合、mysqldumpコマンド入力時もパスワード省略できるか」へ変更した方が適切な気もするのですが、まだ何か勘違いしているかもしれないため、今一度、疑問点を整理したいと思います。

Comment: 現状追記しました。testユーザでhoge.shを実行すると正しく動作しますが、rootユーザでhoge.shを実行すると正しく動作しません

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_config_editor` で設定した内容は ~$HOME/.mylogin.cnf` に保存されます。

`root` で `mysqldump` 実行すると `/root/.mylogin.cnf` を参照しようとしますが、このファイルが存在しないので、認証に失敗していると思います。

恐らく `mysql_config_editor` を設定したのが `test` ユーザだったというオチでは？と思いました。

> 1 15 * * * root /bin/bash /home/test/hoge.sh

crontab の 6番目のフィールドに `root` と書かれているので `hoge.sh` は root ユーザの権限で実行されています。これを `test` に書き換えみてください。

Answer (score 0):

よく見たらユーザ名記載していますね……

`cron.d`で自動実行する処理については"root"の指定が出来るかと思いますが、
`crontab`については`crontab`の実行ユーザの権限で処理が行われるため
"root"で実行していない限り"root"の権限で処理は行えないはずです。

また、crontabはユーザ毎に実行したユーザが所有者でcrontabのファイルが作成されますが、
上記のことからして、crontabファイルの権限を変えたりしてしまうとcronが実行されません。
(セキュリティ的に当たり前ですよね)

色んなユーザの権限で複数処理したいなら"cron.d"に記載するか
そもそもの実行権限を持つユーザでcrontabを編集するといいです。

Answer (score 0):

crontab から実行される環境では、`HOME=/` になっているため、/root/.my.cnf や /root/.mylogin.cnf が読み込めないのではないでしょうか。
hoge.sh に `export HOME=/root` と設定するとどうでしょうか。